# How to read specifc value under 1 node Android Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a data structure that looks like this

```
TABLENAME {
USERID { 
USERID: ...
DATE: ....
}
}
```

I want to only read / retrive the DATE value, how can I do that?

I tried:

```
Log.d("Print Date", snapshotValue.get("DATE"));
```

but it doesn't work it says required string found object.

Basically I want to do something like this, if it can be done without using MAP;

```
String date = snapshot.getValue("DATE");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
snapshot.child("DATE").getValue().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this if you using POJO for your data.

```
   Log.d("Print Date", snapshotValue.getDate());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it without annoying `Map` data structure. Create a class `UserDetails.java` for example. Define getters and setter for private variables `mDate` and `mUserId` in it.

The way to retrieve your data then:

`String date = snapshot.getValue(UserDetails.class).getDate();`